# How to make an embedded question from "What time is it?"

Tags: questions

If the original question is "What time is it?" and I want to communicate it to another person, are these Embedded Questions OK?

> - I don't know what time is it.

or

> - I didn't know what time was it. (if communicated later)

Comment: An "embedded question" does not invert the subject and auxiliary verb: "I don't know what time it is."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easy way to find the word order in an embedded question is to make an *in situ* question with the embedded section. To make an in situ question, we just take a normal sentence and put the appropriate question word in the place of the missing information:

- His name is **what**?
- He is **who**?
- **Who** killed JR?
- You met my elephant **where**?
- It is **what time**?

To make the embedded clause, move the *wh* word to the front of the clause but don't change anything else. If the *wh* word is already at the front, still don't change anything:

- ... **what** his name is.
- ... **who** he is.
- ... **who** killed JR.
- ... **where** you met my elephant.
- ... **what** time it is.

You can then embed this in the main sentence. Let's use *I don't know* for the beginning of the sentence:

- I don't know what his name is.
- I don't know who he is.
- I don't know who killed JR.
- I don't know where you met my elephant.
- I don't know what time it is.

So, for the Original Poster's example the first example needs to be *I don't know what time it is*. For the second example we can test it like this:

- It was **what time**
- ... **what time** it was.
- I didn't know what time it was.

This shows that the Original Poster needs to change round *was* and *it* to make their sentence good.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: I had to upvote this answer simply for your "You met my elephant where?" example. I really like how you broke your explanation down into steps, and it helped me understand rationally what I already knew intuitively. So you can stop hoping, it was helpful to at least one person ;)

Comment: @ColleenV I can confirm that it was helpful to at least two persons now.

Comment: The question was “What time is it?” – present tense. Why did you switch to the past tense? “I don’t know what time it was,” is a good answer to someone asking when something in the past happened, but if someone is asking for the current time, the response would be “I don’t know what time it **is**.”

Comment: @KRyan: The OP asked about *both* "I don't know what time it is" and "I didn't know what time it was".