# I wondered what are your plans? & I wondered what your plans are

Tags: questions

Are Both

"I wondered what are your plans?"

&

I wondered what your plans are."

Correct?

There is a little difference in the the existence of quotation mark.

Comment: [How to make an embedded question from “What time is it?”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53031/how-to-make-an-embedded-question-from-what-time-is-it/53039#53039).

Comment: Tell me what time is it? & Tell me what time it is. I guess.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do mean the same with the caveat that the first example

> I wondered what are your plans?

Would normally require a comma

> I wondered, what are your plans?

or a swap to

> I wondered what were your plans (eg for the weekend)?

Comment: Hi @Rathony maybe a line call, it's certainly not indicative. As I understand it, the Subjunctive mood (and I only really got into it after I started to learn French)  can be used in cases where something is anticipated but uncertain - relating to hypotheticals. Happy to be corrected though

Comment: I think there's enough of a grey area there to make a good ELU conversation. Probably a bit OTT for here - I'll edit to avoid confusion