# "I wonder what they are doing" or "I wonder what are they doing"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which sentence is correct.

> I wonder what they are doing.
>
> I wonder what are they doing?

Comment: In English, we reverse the normal *subject + verb* sequence of #1 when forming questions. But syntactically speaking, example #2 is a ***statement***, not a question (you're asserting that you wonder about something, not actually ***asking*** the question). Native speakers do *sometimes* blur the distinction between question and statement syntax like this (particularly in very casual conversational contexts), but mostly it's something non-native speakers do. I suggest you avoid it.

Comment: ...or at least learn to recognise what you're doing here, if only so you can avoid extending it to constructions like ***I don't know what are they doing***, which ***only*** non-native speakers are likely to come out with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I wondered what are your plans? & I wondered what your plans are](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93240/i-wondered-what-are-your-plans-i-wondered-what-your-plans-are)

Comment: Both can be correct. The first would certainly be the most common usage. The second could still be used though - usually involves a pause after *wonder* and you could almost imagine *what are they doing* in quotation marks. Thus *I wonder*, "What **are** they doing?" Possibly more as a verbal thought or ponderance. Maybe you can hear somebody making a lot of noise and you wonder "what on earth are they doing?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder what they are doing.

See [Questions and negatives | LearnEnglish - British Council](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/es/english-grammar-reference/questions-and-negatives):

> We sometimes use phrases like these in front of a statement to ask
>   questions:
>
> Do you know …?     I wonder …     Can you tell me …?
>
> ...
>
> For **wh-questions**, we use the phrases with a **question word**:
>
> Do you know who lives here?
>
> I wonder how much this dress is.
>
> Can you tell me where she comes from?
>
> We often use **do you think …?** after question words:
>
> How much do you think this dress is?
>
> Where do you think she comes from?
>
> Who do you think lives here?